# Calculation of Site Frequency Spectrum (SFS) using STR data

Tags: genetics, biopython, populations

Hi everyone I had a question on if it is possible to calculate (Site Frequency Spectrum)SFS using STR data. Please mention if you know any programm that can be used for that!
I have tried Arlequin but it doesn't offer this option for STR. Personally I haven't find anything that can do this type of calculation with STR!

Thank you!

Comment: @M__ "I have tried Arlequin but ***it doesn't*** offer this option for STR"

Comment: There are two things. First STS - which is a complex algorithm, secondly is the data STR. If Arlequin has the maximum likelihood estimate for STS (which the OP  implying it does), it's easy. This is because Arlequin will process any data format available, STR is simply a data format, not an algorithm. It's about looking at what format would be most suitable and converting the data accordingly to a format Arlequin uses. The Arlequin data types are not rigid like phylogenetics. That is a fairly easy question. If Arlequin doesn't have STS (the algorithm), finding an STS algorithms is not trivial.

Comment: The parsing operation might be a little complicated - but it's not hard and someone has probably written a parsing script, not necessarily STR -> Arlequin, but STR to an intermediate format that will pass into the official Arlequin data parser.